# Parsing serialized Array (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and one of my meta key values is stored like this:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:8:"Religion";}
```

I'm trying to figure out the easiest way in PHP to parse this so I can extract "Religion" or really any of the elements in a clean manner.

Hope this makes sense - thanks!!!

Loren

Answer (score 8, accepted):

that is a serialized array, [use unserialize()](https://www.php.net/unserialize)

```
$array = unserialize('a:1:{i:0;s:8:"Religion";}');
echo $array[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in PHP 5.2 and above:

```
list($thatWord) = unserialize($metaKeyValue);
```

You then have the string `"Religion"` in `$thatWord`.

The string you have:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:8:"Religion";}
```

Is a serialized array. If you retrieve it from within wordpress, you would get an `Array` instead of a string. I assume you pull it from the database directly, so you need to [`unserialize`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/unserialize) it your own.