# How to decode WordPress metadata array

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using AWS S3 plugin for WordPress and trying to switch back manually.
The plugin creates a new meta that *encodes* an array with curly brackets and string count. It looks like this:

```
[amazonS3_info] => Array ( [0] => 
 a:2:{s:6:"bucket";s:7:"test123";s:3:"key";s:56:"wp-content/uploads/2019/08/test.jpg"
;} )
```

Is this PHP or WordPress array? How do I encode and decode it?

Also, curious as to what's the point of the item and string count? Why not good old json?

Comment: That is a `serialize()` string so use `unserialize()` on it to make it back into a PHP Array. Not JSON because `serialize()` was here first, a long time ago.

Comment: @RiggsFolly awesome!  I spent an hour trying to figure it out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicated of this question:
[Parsing Serialized Array Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110725/parsing-serialized-array-wordpress?rq=4)

Fastest solution is: [use unserialize](https://www.php.net/unserialize)

You have some error in the last key-value pair: s:56

s:56 means that the next string will have 56 characters, but in your case are 35.

Changing this value to have valid string count you have something like that: 'a:2:{s:6:"bucket";s:7:"test123";s:3:"key";s:35:"wp-content/uploads/2019/08/test.jpg";}'

```
$serialized = 'a:2:{s:6:"bucket";s:7:"test123";s:3:"key";s:35:"wp-content/uploads/2019/08/test.jpg";}'
$unserialized = unserialize( $serialized )
```

You get in $unserialized:

```
Array(
   [bucket] => test123
   [key] => wp-content/uploads/2019/08/test.jpg
)
```